# How do you loop through JS set (ES6) values using iterator object?

Tags: javascript, iterator, set

I'm trying to compare all the values in a set. I read about using Set.values() to get an iterator object with all set values. However my loop isn't getting the values as wanted. Why isn't this working and what can I do to properly iterate over the values in a set? Thanks.

```
function greatestVal(arr) {

    let answer = 0;
    const numbers = new Set()

    //store all arr nums in a set to remove duplicates
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      numbers.add(arr[i])
    }

    const iterator = numbers.values()

    for(var num of iterator){
      if(iterator[num]>answer){
        answer=iterator[num];
      }
    }
    return answer;
};
```

Comment: `Set` has no `set`. just `add`. better take `Map` for key and a value.

Comment: You meant to use `for of` instead of `for in`.

Comment: do you have some data to test and the wanted result?

Comment: You seem to want a `Map`, not a `Set`.

Comment: My mistake, I used a Map too in the original code, but edited it to post here. I do actually want a set and updated the post to reflect that. I want the code to take in [2,4,7,7] and return 7.

Comment: Update I changed the "in" to "for" and the function is still not working as expected.

Comment: If you are using an iterator and a `for of` loop, it's just `num>answer` instead of `iterator[num]>answer`